# return a plot for each level of a factor in r

Tags: r, plot, sapply

I want to produce an X,Y plot for each separate ID from the dataframe 'trajectories' :

```
**trajectories**

X    Y    ID
2    4     1
1    6     1
2    4     1
1    8     2
3    7     2
1    5     2
1    4     3
1    6     3
7    4     3
```

I use the code:

```
sapply(unique(trajectories$ID),(plot(log(abs(trajectories$X)+0.01),log((trajectories$Y)+0.01))))
```

But this does not seem to work since the error:

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
c("'(plot(log(abs(trajectories$X)+0.01),log((trajectories$Y)' is not a function,      character or symbol", "'    0.01)))' is not a function, character or symbol")
```

Is there a way to rewrite this code so that i get a separate plot for each ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ggplot2` package for this nicely:

```
library(ggplot2)
trajectories <- structure(list(X = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L), Y = c(4L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 4L), ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("X", "Y", "ID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

ggplot(trajectories, aes(x=log(abs(X) + 0.01), y=log(Y))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap( ~ ID)
```

For what its worth, the reason your cod is failing is exactly what the error says.  the second argument to `sapply` needs to be a function.  If you define your plot code as a function:

```
myfun <- function(DF) {
  plot(log(abs(DF$X) + 0.01), log(DF$Y))
}
```

But this will not split your data on `ID`.  You could also use the `plyr` or `data.table` package to do this splitting and plotting but you will need to write the plots to a file or they will close as each new plot is created.

Comment: Wow the ggplot2 package is exactly what i need! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

The `lattice` package is useful here.

```
library(lattice)
# Make the data frame
X <- c(2,1,2,1,3,1,1,1,7) 
Y <- c(4,6,4,8,7,5,4,6,4)   
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
trajectories <- data.frame(X=X, Y=Y, ID=ID)

# Plot the graphs as a scatter ploy by ID
xyplot(Y~X | ID,data=trajectories)

# Another useful solution is to treat ID as a factor
# Now, the individual plots are labeled
xyplot(Y~X | factor(ID),data=trajectories)
```

Answer (score 1):

Even the with basic R this is possible. Using the iris Dataset:

```
coplot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width | Species, data = iris)
```